# sklearn GridSearchCV : ValueError: X has 21 features per sample; expecting 19

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to run GridSearchCV for Logistic Regression in sklearn and the code is giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: X has 21 features per sample; expecting 19
```

The shapes of the training and testing data are

```
X_train.shape
(891L, 21L)  

X_test.shape
(418L, 21L)
```

The code I'm using to run the GridSearchCV with is

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
logistic = LogisticRegression()

parameters = [{'C' : [1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0],
               'fit_intercept' : ['True', 'False'],
               'intercept_scaling' : [0, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
               'class_weight' : ['auto'],
               'random_state' : [26],
               'tol' : [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
               }]

logistic = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(),
                        parameters,
                        cv=3,
                        refit=True,
                        verbose=1)

logistic = logistic.fit(X_train, y_train)
logit_pred = logistic.predict(X_test)
```

The traceback I'm getting is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Code\kaggle\titanic\titanic.py in <module>()
    351 
    352 
--> 353     logistic = logistic.fit(X_train, y_train)
    354 
    355     logit_pred = logistic.predict(X_test)

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    594 
    595         """
--> 596         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    597 
    598 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
    376                                     train, test, self.verbose, parameters,
    377                                     self.fit_params, return_parameters=True)
--> 378             for parameters in parameter_iterable
    379             for train, test in cv)
    380 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.pyc in __call__(self, iterable)
    651             self._iterating = True
    652             for function, args, kwargs in iterable:
--> 653                 self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
    654 
    655             if pre_dispatch == "all" or n_jobs == 1:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.pyc in dispatch(self, func, args, kwargs)
    398         """
    399         if self._pool is None:
--> 400             job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
    401             index = len(self._jobs)
    402             if not _verbosity_filter(index, self.verbose):

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.pyc in __init__(self, func, args, kwargs)
    136         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    137         # arguments in memory
--> 138         self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
    139 
    140     def get(self):

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.pyc in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters)
   1238     else:
   1239         estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
-> 1240     test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
   1241     if return_train_score:
   1242         train_score = _score(estimator, X_train, y_train, scorer)

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.pyc in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
   1294         score = scorer(estimator, X_test)
   1295     else:
-> 1296         score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
   1297     if not isinstance(score, numbers.Number):
   1298         raise ValueError("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s) instead."

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\scorer.pyc in _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
    174 def _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs):
    175     """Function that wraps estimator.score"""
--> 176     return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
    177 
    178 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.pyc in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    289         """
    290         from .metrics import accuracy_score
--> 291         return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
    292 
    293 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.pyc in predict(self, X)
    213             Predicted class label per sample.
    214         """
--> 215         scores = self.decision_function(X)
    216         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    217             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.pyc in decision_function(self, X)
    194         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
    195             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
--> 196                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
    197 
    198         scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,

ValueError: X has 21 features per sample; expecting 19
```

Why is GridSearchCV expecting a different number of features than the dataset contains?

UPDATE:

Thanks for the response Andy. The datasets are all type numpy.ndarray and dtype is float64.

```
type(X_Train)    type(y_train)    type(X_test)
numpy.ndarray    numpy.ndarray    numpy.ndarray
```

The steps right before I bring them into sklearn:

```
train_data = traindf.values
test_data = testdf.values

X_train = train_data[0::, 1::]  # training features
y_train = train_data[0::, 0]    # training targets
X_test = test_data[0::, 0::]    # test features
```

The next step is the GridSearchCV code I typed above...

UPDATE 2: Link to Data

Here is a link to the [datasets](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c8e9xjl0ix8sj4s/AAA6l6WR1setwGCdJTufPH3Fa?dl=0)

Comment: This looks odd. Can you give ``type(X_train)``, ``type(X_test)``, ``type(y_train)``, and also ``X_train.dtype``, ``y_train.dtype`` and ``X_test.dtype``?
The error means that for some reason the data that the classifier was trained with contains only 19 features, which is at odds with ``X_train.shape`` as you gave it above.

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens to ``X_train`` between printing the shape and the fitting?

Comment: Regardless of the number of features I have, this error occurs. GridSearch is always expecting two fewer features than the total number of features in my datasets.

Comment: That is really odd.
Btw, you code does not seem to be copy and pasted, as you write ``type(X_Train)`` with a capital "T".

Comment: Can you try ``LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)``?

Comment: I didn't copy and paste the code where I got the type and dtype, I just did those in the interactive console, they're not actually part of my actual code. So yeah, the capital T was a typo, sorry. The code before the traceback is copied and pasted and so is the code where I take the .values of the pandas dataframes.

Comment: And if I comment out the GridSearch portion of the code, the LogisticRegression runs just fine. I have it save the file as a csv and have confirmed that it generates predictions.

Comment: I have no idea what is happening. Can you provide data and code to reproduce? I would think it is an error in your code, but I don't see any.

Comment: @AndreasMueller: I added the link to the data above. Thank you for taking a look at it. Apologies if the code is difficult to understand, I use some toggle statements to turn code on and off so I can try different features out. I'm sure the PEP contributors would look at me with contempt :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is cause by `intercept_scaling=0`. Looks like a bug in scikit-learn.

Comment: For what it's worth, I wouldn't search over ``intercept_scaling`` in any case. Just leave it as ``1``. I would only search over ``C``.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate the advice.